# Are there characters that performs actions in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, agent-nouns

> There is a need for an analysis of library use to provide a reliable base for the projection of needed resources.

I think *there*, *use* and *base* are subjects, but what are the characters that perform actions?

Answer (score 2):

"Characters that perform actions" are called ***[agents](https://www.google.com/search?q=agent%20meaning&oq=agent%20m&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0i131i433i512j46i175i199i512j0i512l3j46i512j0i512l3.5410j0j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)*** in grammar. The agents are omitted in this sentence, because it is kind of obvious that the people who do such things will carry out this analysis, and anyway you don't know who exactly.

Your sentence has passive meaning:

> An analysis of library use ***needs to be made*** *(by...)*

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/passives-with-and-without-an-agent) explains:

> *Passive structures without an agent* are very common. We use these structures ***when an agent is not important, or is unknown or obvious***:
>
> - *The data was analysed* and *the results have just been published*.
> - I walked to work. *The car’s being repaired*.

Note that, as the other answer explains in detail, from the words you mention, only *there* is a subject, but a dummy one, with no meaning in itself.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering.

Comment: We use these structures when an agent is not important, or is unknown or obvious, and often inelegant:

_The data was analysed by analysts and the results have just been published by the publishers the analysts employ_.

Answer (score 1):

*There* is a "dummy subject", as described here:
[Cambridge *dummy subjects*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/dummy-subjects)

"There as a dummy subject
*There* operates as a dummy subject in the construction *there is* or *there are*. There is/are indicates that something or someone exists or is in a particular place or situation
(example)   *There’s a woman waiting outside who wants to talk to you.*
(The real subject is the woman – she is waiting outside.)."

The real subject in your sentence is *need*; the sentence says that a need exists.

The word *use* is the object of the preposition *of*.
The word *base* is the direct object of *provide* in a purpose clause.

There are no characters performing actions; rather, a statement is made that a future action is needed.